# Why files are downloading instead of viewing in browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

```
@RequestMapping( value= "/get/{imageName}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage1(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName) throws IOException {
    final Optional<ImageModel> retrievedImage = imageModelRepository.findByName(imageName);
    ImageModel img = new ImageModel(retrievedImage.get().getName(), retrievedImage.get().getType(),retrievedImage.get().getPicByte());
    byte[] imageArray= retrievedImage.get().getPicByte();
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(imageArray);
    

}
```

Comment: I would guess: because of the way your front end code is coded. Showing us the REST endpoint doesn't tell us what your browser is showing you, and what you are doing there. So please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. You see, just putting up a question title and throwing some java code at us does **not** enable us to help you.

Comment: You specified response `Content-Type` as [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream), which represents "arbitrary binary data". Since the browser doesn't know how to show that, it just gives you the option to download the file. If you want the browser to display the image, you need to specify the appropriate `Content-Type`, e.g. [`image/png`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-Type` of `application/octet-stream` forces it to always download.

You can try something like follows:

```java
...
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("image/jpeg"));
...
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
...
ResponseEntity<byte[]> returnValue = new ResponseEntity<>(imageArray, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

return returnValue;
```

Comment: What else we can add instead of  APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE to view the file in browser?

Comment: The file may be anything like image , pdf or text

Comment: I edited my answer. You can try replacing the `image/jpeg` dynamically with the correct content type of the file.

Comment: I have the byte[] of original document how can we convert it in its original document and view it in browser using below code 

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("image/jpeg"));
...
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);

Comment: Check if the new update I've added answers your comment.